# MySQLConnector constantly reaching max connections (4 total)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core, mysql-connector

I'm using **ClearDB** on **Azure** with 4 total connections available. **ASP.NET Core 1.1**.
Also I'm using **Ngrok** to expose my localhost where my API is running.
When I make synchronous requests, my **API** sometimes uses the same connection, but in a short time makes a new one, leaving the old ones sleeping.
They take a long time to die and I end up with 4 connections made by the same user with the same remote host IP but with a different port for each.
They are not used and have a command equal to "sleep" according to the **ClearDB** portal.
I'm thinking that **Ngrok** could be causing the issue. However, when I try to call `MySqlConnection.ClearPool(Connection);` my API request never finish, they just get stuck at that command forever.
I also call `Close` and `Dispose` at the end of each request.
Any ideas?

```
function1() {
    Connection.Open();

    var Cmd = Connection.CreateCommand() as MySqlCommand;
    Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE senderID=@SenderID";
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SenderID", UserData.SenderID);
    var result = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(result.HasRows) {
        result.Read();
    }
    Cmd.Connection.Close();
    Cmd.Dispose();
    result.Dispose();
}

public bool DoesUserExist() {
    var Cmd = Connection.CreateCommand() as MySqlCommand;
    Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT senderID FROM users WHERE senderID=@SenderID";
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SenderID", UserData.SenderID);
    var result = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
    bool UserExisits = result.HasRows;
    Cmd.Connection.Close();
    Cmd.Dispose();
    result.Dispose();
    return UserExisits;
}

function2() {
    var Cmd = Connection.CreateCommand() as MySqlCommand;
    long Time = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();

    if(DoesUserExist()) {
        Cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE users SET lastcontact=@time, contextS=@contextS WHERE senderID=@SenderID";
    } else {
        Cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users(senderID, contextS, lastcontact) VALUES (@SenderID, @contextS, @time)";
    } 
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contextS", UserData.Context);
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", Time);
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SenderID", UserData.SenderID);
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Cmd.Connection.Close();
    Cmd.Dispose();

    Connection.Close();
    Connection.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Are your connections wrapped in a `Using` block? This is often more reliable than manually calling `Close` and `Dispose`, and should ensure the connection is properly terminated. It may not solve the issue, but might narrow it down. When the connection does time out, are you catching an exception? A stack trace could be useful here.

Comment: The only exception I get is max_connections reached. No timeout exceptions. I'll try a using block and report back. Regarding dependency, I'm using scoped too btw. But it doesn't seem to really be doing anything noticeable.

Comment: Is there an inner exception nested in the timeout exception? That has caught me out before.... I suspect that NGrok is causing issues here. I've never used it before, but did have issues with timeouts on IPSEC tunnels used for SQL requests in the past. Our solution was to ramp up the connection limit and recycle stale tunnels periodically.

Comment: @Alex: how would using be more different then calling `.Dispose()`? `using` statement/block is a wrapper for `var object = someObject; try { ... } finally { object?.Dispose() }`

Comment: @Tseng Calling `Dispose` manually can be done without the object being created in a `try...catch` block. If you stick to `using` blocks, the `try...catch` is always present.

Comment: Using this method does not work either, it just creates a new connection with a new port. It also stops me using scoped dependancy injection, because I have to create a new object every time I need to reuse the connection in the scope of the current request, where I before I only closed the connection at the end of the request. Regardless of that, do you know what the Remote Host on ClearDB is?

Comment: Why would the clearpool connection function hang?

Comment: @Alex: No, when you use `using` statement, then `catch`-Block **is not present**. it's only a `try/finally` block, without any exception handling. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx. Also in context of ASP.NET Core its not really recommended to instantiate DbContext (in case of EF) and use disposing but let the DI handle it (DbContext is resolved as scope within ASP.NET Core, means per request, not per query/connection)

Comment: @Jams: Maybe you post some code of your usage, how you register it with DI etc. I suppose you are not using EF Core are you?

Comment: @Tseng My appologies, you are indeed right.

Comment: please paste your code where the connection stuck !

Comment: I have pasted the code. the order is function1 then function2. This time however, I have added Pooling=false to the connection string and when I call connection.close(); in function 2 it hangs there. Also that is the spot where it ClearPool was and where it would get stuck when pooling was enabled. I can confirm that the connection is indeed successful. I just can't close it.

Comment: @Saif Can you help?